# How to return all the distinct foreign keys in a Django view?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

Here is my model.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

And my view.py:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'home_page': "active",
        'categories': SubCategory.objects.order_by('category').distinct('category').values_list('category'),
    }
    return render(request, 'candidates/home.html', context)
```

and my template:

```
<ul>
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li>{{ category }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

and instead of seing the Category names, I see their ID

[image]

How can I get their names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the *name* of the category, so:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'home_page': "active",
        'categories': SubCategory.objects.order_by('category__name').distinct('category__name').values_list('category__name', flat=True),
    }
    return render(request, 'candidates/home.html', context)
```

That being said, querying the `Subcategory` does not make much sense. You can get a list of `Category`s with:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'home_page': "active",
        'categories': Category.objects.order_by('name'),
    }
    return render(request, 'candidates/home.html', context)
```

Or if you want only `Category`s with at least one subcategory, you can work with:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'home_page': "active",
        'categories': Category.objects.filter(subcategory__isnull=False).order_by('name').distinct(),
    }
    return render(request, 'candidates/home.html', context)
```

You can simplify the `__str__` of the `Category` with:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

**EDIT**: You can order the `Category`s by the number of subcategories (in descending order) with:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'home_page': "active",
        'categories': Category.objects.annotate(
            nsub=Count('subcategory')
        ).order_by('-nsub')
    }
    return render(request, 'candidates/home.html', context)
```

Comment: Just one small thing, what if I would like to order the categories by "count of sub categories" ?

Comment: @VincentRoye: see edit at the bottom of the answer.